# setCustomValidity() error message string length constraint in firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, firefox

I ran into an strange issue on Firefox using a long message (more than 255 chars) for the setCustomValidity(message) function. In the [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity) I couldn't find any information about any message length constraints but it seems that Firefox cuts the message to 255 characters. Does anyone have more information about this?

```
var elem = document.getElementById('set-custom-validity'),
    form = document.getElementById('form'),
    longErrorMessage = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata This is not shown in Firefox';

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){

    elem.setCustomValidity(longErrorMessage)

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/s8jzm589/)

Comment: The [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/constraints.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity) also does not specify any length. My understanding is that it would be up to the user agent vendor to set a maximum length of their choosing. It may be unfortunate that Firefox limited it to 255 characters, but I guess there has to be some limit.